# Debian Systemd boot logs - show on boot

Tags: debian, systemd

I now want to show the logs that systemd prints on boot. In the debian newer versions this doesn't happen.

Comment: Using `dmesg` perhaps?

Comment: Pressing `TAB` key during startup hide 'plymouth` and display usual log.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `plymouth` package installed (= providing a splash screen at boot), you could run `plymouth-set-default-theme details; update-initramfs -u`. Try this first to see if it provides the sort of display you'd like.

For more detailed logging from `systemd` specifically, you could edit `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`, uncomment the line that says `#ForwardToConsole=no` and change it to `ForwardToConsole=yes`. Again, run `update-initramfs -u` after this to ensure it will take effect as early in the boot process as possible.

If you don't have `plymouth` installed, or want even more detailed information from the kernel, edit `/etc/default/grub` and remove the keywords `quiet` and `splash` from any `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX*` settings, then run `update-grub`.

Comment: Thank you, let me try